# How to trigger job creation in jenkins server and automatically create same job in another jenkins server

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Any plug-in or Jenkins job to create a job with the same configuration on another server.?

Is it possible with docker?

Comment: I have successfully used the [Job DSL Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki) in the past. I am however voting to close this question as it is currently asking for tool recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to copy the job xml config from under jenkins_home/jobs/ folder to the equivalent location on the other server and restart jenkins.

This has nothing to do with docker. Its purely a jenkins thing.

Check [here](https://staxmanade.com/2015/01/how-to-migrate-a-jenkins-job-to-new-jenkins-server/) for a full list of option available.

Comment: Rather than copying, pasting and restarting manually. I'm thinking of doing it automatically. Just like the job cloner plugin, is there a plug-in to do that?

Comment: Can we trigger the job creation on Jenkins server?

Comment: @SriTejaKumarSamudrala, are you ok with using jenkins api for triggering job creation?

Comment: No, any documentation provided will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be that you use [Jenkins Job Builder](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeoLWVh4LYAhWGApoKHdhVAfEQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.openstack.org%2Finfra%2Fjenkins-job-builder%2F&usg=AOvVaw2zdcmGAZ56bj-wDr0QWI-l).

With Jenkins Job builder, you store the definition of jobs in source control.

Whenever you need to create a job, you can just trigger the jenkins-job command towards "any Jenkins Master" and a similar job will be created.

The address of targeted jenkins master is given in the config file.